# How to get substring from string with whitespace in C#

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have string s as given below , I want to have return substring  with space like `123 456 7`

```
string s = "123  456  789    012  7892";

string sa = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s", "").Substring(0, 7);

//string sa = "123456"; -- getting this after substring 
// sa = "123 456 7" -- expected this after substring
```

Comment: So, you wan tot take the first 7 characters but ignore the whitespace? Something like that?

Comment: you need to clarify on what basis are you expecting this output

Comment: substring should return value with space even if pass index such as from sa.substring(3,7) with white space. @Natrium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it using `Split` and `Join` methods

```
string s = "123  456  789    012  7892";

var splitted = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var joined = string.Join(' ', splitted);
var subString = joined.Substring(0, 9);  // : 123 456 7
```

Comment: @Hosseing Please can you help what will we do if we have multiple space between each string and we want to print data as it is

Comment: @Hossein-Narimani-Rad I tested your code in Wpf but the Join method has no overload that have Char , so: var joined = string.Join(" ", splitted);

Comment: @jprathore can you make an example to see what you exactly mean

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ")` for replace multiple spaces in a string with one space

```
string s = "123  456  789    012  7892";
string newS = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
Console.WriteLine(newS.Substring(0, 7+2)); // 2 for spaces
```

> result: "123 456 7"